# Can a kubernetes Deployment inject the service nodeport as an environment variable?

Tags: kubernetes, netflix-eureka

Inside a service yaml file, you can use jsonpath to select a named nodeport value like so:

```
    - name: MY_NODE_PORT
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.ports[?(@.name=="http")].nodePort
```

However, in my deployment yaml file, I would like to have an environment variable like `MY_NODE_PORT` above that is exposed to the container to the pod. I happen to have combined my service and deployment into a single file for me to `kubectl create -f`. Is it possible to select the named service nodeport in the deployment section, rather than in the service section?

My purpose is to register a Kubernetes service and deployment to a legacy service discovery mechanism, in this case Netflix OSS Eureka.

Comment: This is a hack, but if you set the `SERVICE_NAME` as an environmental variable then this will work inside a pod to get the nodeport:

    `curl --silent --fail \
     --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
    https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/$SERVICE_NAME \
    | jq '.spec.ports[] | select(.name=="http") | .nodePort'`

Comment: it's no difference for kubernetes if you have deployment and service in one file or two. So, no, you can't refer from the deployment spec to the service spec.
May I ask what your goal is? Why do you need the nodeport in the deployment? Maybe there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: btw, it's also possible to add the nodeport to the service spec, so you know it upfront. But then it's your responsibility to make sure that there are no port collisions.

Comment: I need to do service registry of a kubernetes service outside of the kubernetes cluster to Eureka in a legacy Netflix OSS microservice environment.

Comment: ok. What about using Ingresses? You could create an Ingress for each deployment, and e.g. use the deployment name (or whatever is unique for your applications) as Ingress path. Then you could access your apps under http(s)://<ingress-controller-ip>:<ingress-controller-port>/<deploymentname>, where ip and port are fixed, and you use the path for your service registry instead of the nodeport. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ for more infos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in [Janos Lenart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371954/janos-lenart)'s answer and [Marc Sluiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763788/marc-sluiter) commented, a service and a deployment are different resources and might as easily be specified in separate files. They have no direct knowledge of one another, and, even if you name the service NodePort port, unless you explicitly specify the service NodePort port value (e.g. something from 30000 to 32767) you won't be able to specify what the pod environment variable should be to match it. While you can hard code the NodePort port value like that, as [Janos Lenart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371954/janos-lenart) suggested, but it's brittle and not recommended.

While Kubernetes provides a number of handy environment variables to pods, it is not possible for a pod environment variable to reference a service nodeport port value that was dynamically assigned by kubernetes.

However, the Pod **does** have access to talk to the Kubernetes API server, and the API server will be able to reply back with information about the service, such as the nodeport. So a Pod can ask the API server for a service's NodePort port value. I created a [kubernetes service and deployment with simple sidecar pod](https://github.com/StevenACoffman/kubernetes-eureka-sidecar) as a proof of concept.

[My example here](https://github.com/StevenACoffman/kubernetes-eureka-sidecar) handles registering a Kubernetes NodePort service with an (external or internal) Netflix OSS Eureka service registry. This might be useful to others for bridging Kubernetes to other legacy service discovery mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

You automatically have a number of environment variables in the containers. You do need to make sure your Service is created **before** your deployment.

As an example, for a Service named mysql (in the same namespace) you will have variables like this:

```
MYSQL_PORT="tcp://10.96.0.3:3306"
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP="tcp://10.96.0.3:3306"
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR="10.96.0.3"
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT="3306"
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PROTO="tcp"
MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST="10.96.0.3"
MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT="3306"
MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT_MYSQL="3306"
```

As an alternative you can also make use of the [cluster DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) service special attention to SRV records).

Comment: So the `MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT_MYSQL="3306"` shows the port value, but not the NodePort value that may be dynamically assigned from 30000-32767 range if the service is type nodePort. How can that value be communicated to the pod/container?